# function remains undefined after binding too in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried out this code. Everything seems fine to me but compiler say's onDismiss is undefined? Please help me out on this one....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const list=[{title:'React',id:0},{title:'Redux',id:1}];

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={list,};
    this.onDismiss=this.onDismiss.bind(this); }

    onDismiss(id){

    const isnotid=item=>item.id!==id;
    const uplist=this.state.list.filter(isnotid);
    this.setState({list : uplist});
  }
    render() {

    return( <div className="App">
         {this.state.list.map(item=>
         <div key={item.id}>
         <span>
          {item.title}
         </span>
         <button onClick={()=>onDismiss(item.id)} type="button">
          Dismiss
         </button>
         </div>)}</div>);
    }
}
export default App;
```

It is a simple app that displays a list. A dismiss button is used to remove any unneeded content. Basically, I am just practicing Reactjs but don't have the clue about why my Ondismiss( The function to change content by updating component state) function is Undefined as described by compiler.
Fixed typo's and little mistakes but it onDismiss function still remains undefined!

Comment: call it as this.onDismiss()

Comment: It says `onDimiss` in the example code.

Comment: dude corrected it but still it stays undefined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

`<button onClick={()=>onDismiss(item.id)} type="button">`

with

```
<button onClick={()=>this.onDismiss(item.id)} type="button">
```

Comment: thanks Yadav, but now it say's "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: @BilalKazmi You have written `onDimiss` in your question.

Comment: your function definition has a typo error. check onDismiss method spelling. upvote to @Tholle

Comment: @BilalKazmi With Manoj's fix, and with the typo fixed, [it will work](https://codesandbox.io/s/24n32937jr).

Comment: it still says 'undefined'?